# Create file/folder on Shared drive via service account

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using a G-Suite Google Drive and Service account to connect to a Shared Drive.  I'm using the PHP API library.  I have previously made this work with the "regular" Google drive but we are moving to shared drive (aka Team Drive)

I can use files->listFiles() to get the file list, using:

```
    $options = array('pageSize'          => 100,
                 'corpora'               => 'drive',
                 'supportsTeamDrives'    => true,
                 'includeTeamDriveItems' => true,
                 'teamDriveId'           => $sharedID,
                 'fields'                => "nextPageToken, files(id, name)",
                 'q'                     => "'" . $pParentFolderID . "' in parents "
               . " and name = \"" . $pFolderName . "\" "
               . " and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' "
               . " and not trashed"
);
try{
    $files_list = $this->drive_service->files->listFiles($optParams);
```

This works and gives me the ID for the specific file/folder I ask for.

However, attempting to create a folder in the top folder on the drive results in 404 error, saying that the file/folder is not found, even though I have just retrieved the correct ID from it.

```
        $param =array(  'supportsAllDrives' => true,
                'supportsTeamDrives'    => true,
                'teamDriveId'           => $SharedID,
                'parents'               => array($pParentFolderID),
                'name'                  => $pFolderName,
                'mimeType'              => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder');

    $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile($param);

try {
    $folderObj = $this->drive_service->files->create($fileMetadata, array('fields' => 'id'));
```

I have tried all kinds of permutations of this, but always get the 404.  I have verified many times that the file ID for the parent is correct.  I have tried using teamdriveid, driveid and various other options.

This is the data that I send and the data I get back from Google:

```
array(6) {
  ["supportsAllDrives"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["supportsTeamDrives"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["teamDriveId"]=>
  string(19) "0ALay-iFeEOX6Uk9PVA"
  ["parents"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(33) "1oI72fkTb-AObYWBEOI-ykS5eDYg3L2ar"
  }
  ["name"]=>
  string(9) "FieldTest"
  ["mimeType"]=>
  string(34) "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
}

Trying to create:
Error from Google:array(1) {
  ["error"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["errors"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["domain"]=>
        string(6) "global"
        ["reason"]=>
        string(8) "notFound"
        ["message"]=>
        string(50) "File not found: 1oI72fkTb-AObYWBEOI-ykS5eDYg3L2ar."
        ["locationType"]=>
        string(9) "parameter"
        ["location"]=>
        string(6) "fileId"
      }
    }
    ["code"]=>
    int(404)
    ["message"]=>
    string(50) "File not found: 1oI72fkTb-AObYWBEOI-ykS5eDYg3L2ar."
  }
}
```

This process works with the "regular" drive, but fails on the Shared Drive.

Anyone have an idea what is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are providing `supportsAllDrives` in the request body, when you should be providing it as a query parameter, as specified [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create#request_1). Also, `supportsTeamDrives` and `teamDriveId` are not needed (and they are deprecated). So you should change this:

```
$param =array(  'supportsAllDrives' => true,
                'supportsTeamDrives'    => true,
                'teamDriveId'           => $SharedID,
                'parents'               => array($pParentFolderID),
                'name'                  => $pFolderName,
                'mimeType'              => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder');
```

To this:

```
$param =array(  'parents'               => array($pParentFolderID),
                'name'                  => $pFolderName,
                'mimeType'              => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder');
```

Also, as I said, you should provide `supportsAllDrives` as a parameter when making the call. So you should change this:

```
$folderObj = $this->drive_service->files->create($fileMetadata, array('fields' => 'id'));
```

To this:

```
$folderObj = $this->drive_service->files->create($fileMetadata, array('fields' => 'id', 'supportsAllDrives' => true));
```

Because you are providing `supportsAllDrives` in the request body and not as a parameter, you cannot access shared drives.

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: This does not work.  I get "(create) unknown parameter: 'supportsAllDrives'" exception in Resource.php After tracing this through the files into Drive.php, it only lists the "fileId as the optional parameter for the create method:
`'create' => array(
  'path' => 'files/{fileId}/comments',
  'httpMethod' => 'POST',
  'parameters' => array(
    'fileId' => array(
      'location' => 'path',
      'type' => 'string',
      'required' => true,
    ),
  ),`
So, I'm not sure what the solution is.

Comment: @ArnorBaldvinsson Apparently you are [not using an up-to-date library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1637). Check the link I provided and make the instructions specified there in order to use an updated library that supports `supportsAllDrives`. Also, the method resource you are looking at in your last comment is not the one you want. You don't want to create a comment but a file. That's why only `fileId` is listed as parameter. Please let me know if these indications are enough to solve your problem, otherwise I'll look into it in more detail.

Comment: Thanks!  I thought I was using the latest - downloaded from that repo on Github yesterday, but maybe I didn't get everything updated in my project!  Will make sure I have all the latest and let you know how it works out!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!!  I updated all the Google library and it worked!

Comment: This was very helpful. I was going crazy thinking I head SCOPE problems or Permission problems. I'm using the Python library.    The following finally worked.
        if data_forms_folder_id is not None:
            data = {'name': 'My new Sheet 2',
                    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
                    ,'parents': [data_forms_folder_id]
                    }
            sheet = DRIVE.files().create(body=data, supportsAllDrives=True, supportsTeamDrives=True).execute()